# Get text between a group of delimiters

Tags: regex

I have a string of text with four delimiters `ST:` `SI:` `T:` and `I:` that are followed by a sequence of digits and numbers. I need to grab the delimiter as a group called `group` and the digits and numbers as `code`.

```
ST:12YEOR48000FCT:24YEOR48000FCSI:12YEOR13000FCI:12YEOR13000FCT:12YEOR51200FCI:12YEOR14500FCST:12YEOR48000FCT:24YEOR48000FCSI:12YEOR13000FCI:12YEOR13000FCT:12ACTYEI:12ACTYET:32000ACTFCI:13300ACTFC
```

The results should be

```
GROUP CODE
ST:   12YEOR48000FC
T:    24YEOR48000FC
SI:   12YEOR13000F
CI:   12YEOR13000F
CT:   12YEOR51200F
CI:   12YEOR14500FC
ST:   12YEOR48000F
CT:   24YEOR48000FC
SI:   12YEOR13000F
CI:   12YEOR13000F
CT:   12ACTYE
I:    12ACTYE
T:    32000ACTFC
I:    13300ACTFC
```

`(?'group'ST:|SI:|T:|I:)(?'code'.*?)(?<=ST:|SI:|T:|I:|$)`

My thought is that I want grab the starting delimiter as the group, then any character as the code, until another delimiter or end of string is found. The regex I came up with gets the delimiters but not the code.

Thanks for any help.

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/eW0gSV/3)

Comment: Please add the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a positive lookbehind for your `code` group, which won't accomplish the functionality you're looking for.

However, you're on the right track! Removing the `<` to create a positive look*ahead* will achieve what you're looking for:

```
(?'group'ST:|SI:|T:|I:)(?'code'.*?)(?=ST:|SI:|T:|I:|$)
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/eW0gSV/4)

You should also consider optimizing the pattern a bit for maintainability by using nested matching groups to break out the colon token for each of your `group` items. This will make it easier to add `group` codes later and limit the potential of typos (i.e., forgetting the colon in the new `group` code):

```
(?'group'(?:ST|SI|T|I):)(?'code'.*?)(?=(?:ST|SI|T|I):|$)
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/eW0gSV/5)

Comment: @SportsRacer Speaking about optimizations, you may contract it further and you will get `(?<group>S?[TI]:)(?<code>.*?)(?=S?[TI]:|$)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSNnUo/1).